# customized alert dialog search item result wrong

Tags: android, listview, search, adapter

I'm creating an Android application. It has some popup dialog with a search bar. But the problem is: When I search some product using that, the matching items for that search should added to the listview inside the popup dialog, this works fine.

But when I selected the item that searched item inside the popup dialog should save in the object **(OrderView object)** that I previously created, But that stored item inside that object is always wrong **(this happens only, if I search item)**. The problem happens from this code line,

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
```

Because I'm getting **postion** to identify the selected item.

But I don't know how to replace this code line to correct way. I really appreciate your any help. Thank you.

**here is my code :**

```
final List<Product> products_data = dbHelper.productListView();
    if (products_data.size() > 0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Select A Product");
        //insert array to constructor
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_pop_up, null);
        final ProdductPopupAdapter testAdapter = new ProdductPopupAdapter(getContext(), products_data);
        final ListView listView = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.product_list_view);
        TextView cancel_btn = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        final EditText search_view = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_item_search);
        listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);

        search_view.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                final ProdductPopupAdapter testAdapter = new ProdductPopupAdapter(getContext(),dbHelper.searchProductList(search_view.getText().toString()));
                listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
                testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        builder.setView(dialogLayout);

        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            {
                OrderView orderView = new OrderView();
                orderView.setProduct_name(products_data.get(position).getProductName());
                orderView.setProduct_qty(0);
                orderView.setProduct_price(products_data.get(position).getPrice());
                orderView.setNewItemtotal(Double.parseDouble(products_data.get(position).getPrice()));
                orderView.setTotalPrice(products_data.get(position).getPrice());
                orderView.setProduct_id(Integer.parseInt(products_data.get(position).getProductID()));
                myItems.add(orderView);

                calculatePrice(myItems);

                binding.itemList.setAdapter(newOrderListAdaptor);
                newOrderListAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

                alert.dismiss();
            }

        });  
    }
```

[image: All product list is like this (before search)]

[image: When you search item it will update the adapter and display inside the popup, If we think you want to add it to your list then you should select it, now problem will appear]

[image: It added to the list, but wrong input. This is not the selected value, this is the 1st all product list]

Comment: Can you please add a few logs inside onItemClick for the products_data and position. Then we can find the what happened exactly.

Comment: I have update my post, **1st image shows :** All product list is like this (before search). **2nd image shows :** When you search item, it will update the adapter and display inside the popup, If we think you want to add it to your list then you should select it, now problem will appear. **3rd image shows :** It added to the list, but wrong input. This is not the selected value, this is the 1st all product list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. The problem is  `products_data` list is not updated while you are searching items. But you are trying to get items form created and not updated products_data list. **here**

```
OrderView orderView = new OrderView();
orderView.setProduct_name(products_data.get(position).getProductName());
orderView.setProduct_qty(0);
orderView.setProduct_price(products_data.get(position).getPrice());
orderView.setNewItemtotal(Double.parseDouble(products_data.get(position).getPrice()));
orderView.setTotalPrice(products_data.get(position).getPrice());
orderView.setProduct_id(Integer.parseInt(products_data.get(position).getProductID()));
myItems.add(orderView);
```

if you can put your `List<Product> products_data = dbHelper.productListView();`
inside your class and then try to update it while searching items. Hope this will helpful.

**here is the sample :**

```
products_data = dbHelper.productListView();
    final ListView listView;
        if (products_data.size() > 0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            //insert array to constructor
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_pop_up, null);
            testAdapter = new ProdductPopupAdapter(getContext(), products_data);
            listView = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.product_list_view);
            TextView cancel_btn = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
            final EditText search_view = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_item_search);
            listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);

            search_view.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    products_data = dbHelper.searchProductList(s.toString());
                    testAdapter = new ProdductPopupAdapter(getContext(), products_data);
                    listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
                    testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

        builder.setView(dialogLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the onItemClick functionality to the adapter?

Example:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code here
            }
        });
```